# iterating and printing words in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, output

I'm in the process of learning python and I love how much can be accomplished in such a small amount of code but I'm getting confused about the syntax. I'm just trying to iterate through a dictionary and print out each item and value.

Here is my code:

```
words = {}
value = 1

for line in open("test.txt", 'r'):
    for word in line.split():
        print (word)
        try:
            words[word] += 1
        except KeyError:
            #wur you at key?
            print("no")
            words[word]=1

for item in words:
    print ("{",item, ": ", words[item][0], " }")
```

My current print statement doesn't work and I can't find a good example of a large print statement using multiple variables. How would I print this properly?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? It would help if you provided us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), either with the contents of `test.txt` or, better, with `words` just defined in the source code. Then you could show the expected and actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you're trying to print `words[item][0]`, but `words[item]` is always going to be a number, and number can't be indexed.

So, just… don't do that:

```
print ("{",item, ": ", words[item], " }")
```

---

That's enough to fix it, but there are ways you could improve this code:

- `print` with multiple arguments puts a space between each one, so you're going to end up printing `{ item :  3 }`, when you probably didn't want all those spaces. You can fix that by using the keyword argument `sep=''`, but a better solution is to use string formatting or the `%` operator.
- You can get the keys and values at the same time by iterating over `words.items()` instead of `words`.
- You can simplify the whole "store a default value if one isn't already there" by using the `setdefault` method, or by using a `defaultdict`—or, even more simply, you can use a `Counter`.
- You should always close files that you open—preferably by using a `with` statement.
- Be consistent in your style—don't put spaces after some functions but not others.

So:

```
import collections
with open("test.txt") as f:
    words = collections.Counter(word for line in f for word in line.split())
for item, count in words.items():
    print("{%s: %d}" % (item, count))
```

Comment: thanks! I'm trying to solve some basic python problems to get a handle on it and I have a ton to learn yet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `dict.get` and can eliminate try and except block.

```
words = {}

for line in open("test.txt", 'r'):
    for word in line.split():
        print (word)
        words[word] = words.get(word,0) +1

for word,count in words.items():
    print(word,count)
```

`dict.get` it return the key, if present in dictionary else default value
syntax: `dict.get(key[,default])`

you can also override `__missing__`:

```
class my_dict(dict):
    def __missing__(self,key):
        return 0


words = my_dict()

for line in open("test.txt", 'r'):
    for word in line.split():
        print (word)
        words[word] += 1

for word,count in words.items():
    print(word,count)
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to iterate through a dictionary as you're doing here is to loop by key AND value, unpacking the key-value tuple each time through the loop:

```
for item, count in words.items():
    print("{", item, ": ", count, "}")
```

And as a side note, you don't really need that exception handling logic in that loop where you build the array. Dictionaries' `get()` methods can return a default value if the key isn't in the dictionary, simplifying your code to this:

```
words[word] = words.get(word, 0) + 1
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: This is wrong. When you iterate a `dict`, you just get its keys, not its key-value pairs. If you want the latter, you have to use the `items` method (as explained in my answer). Also, this doesn't really explain what's wrong with his code; if you translated his code to use `items`, it would be `for item, word in words.items():` and then `word[0]` in the `print` call, and you'd get the exact same error he started with.

Comment: Fixed to use `items()`. I don't think I particularly have to explain why OP's code is wrong, given that you do this. The code I present in this answer is, in my opinion, the best way to do this; this is because it reads more idiomatically. When I initially posted the answer, it had slipped my mind that `items()` was needed.